# How many ways can a quadratic form represent a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Given $a,b,c,p\in\Bbb N$ with $b^2-4ac<0$ and $p$ is a prime with $\bigg(\frac{b^2-4ac}p\bigg)=1$, how many solutions $(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2$ are there to $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=p?$$

Comment: There is a whole book on the existence of solution in the case $a=1,b=0, c>0$. http://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-x2-ny2-Multiplication/dp/0471190799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing some concepts. If $p$ does not divide the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ and $(\Delta|p) = 1,$ also $\Delta < 0,$ then at least one primitive form of that discriminant does, in fact, represent the prime. One may, further, demand that the form be Gauss reduced, so that we can tell by sight whether it is ambiguous, that is improperly equivalent to itself. If so, and if it does represent the prime, then one expects four representations, of very slightly different appearance. For example, if $a u^2 + c v^2 = p,$ then we have four solutions $(u,v); (-u,-v); (u,-v);(-u,v).$ Only in the extremely special cases of $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 + xy + y^2$ can we get eight representations of a prime.

On the other hand, consider primes for which $(-44|p) = 1.$ These include $3,5.$ But these have no expression as $x^2 + 11 y^2$ Instead, they are represented by the other forms in the class group, a pair of opposite forms, $3 x^2 + 2 xy + 4 y^2$ and  $3 x^2 - 2 xy + 4 y^2$

Comment: I was trying to understand theorem $5.1$ here http://math.columbia.edu/~nsnyder/tutorial/lecture7.pdf It says if D=-4, w=4 and we have 8 representations of p=1 mod 4 with x^2+y^2. It did not make sense.

Comment: really? Can we represent 17 in 8 different ways using $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: @Arul discriminants $-3$ and $-4$ are special. $x^2 + y^2 = 17:$ (1,4), (1,-4)(-1,4), (-1,-4), (4,1)(4,-1)(-4,1)(-4,-1)

Comment: So you count permutation too? Thank you.

Comment: So if you take products of all primes less than $n$ which are $(\Delta|p)=1$, then you should get $w2^{n/2}$ different representations on average with $w=2$ if $\Delta<-4$?

Comment: Sorry one final comment? Is this form $au^2+bv^2$ with $(a,b)=1$ always reduced?

Comment: if $0 < a < b,$ yes. also $a=b=1$

Comment: Thank you this clarifies a lot. I think this is right formulation of problem I am looking at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416256/how-to-find-a-quadratic-form-that-represents-a-prime.