# How many (reduced) quadratic forms represent a given prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms

For a given prime $p$, how many (reduced) quadratic forms represent it?

(inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416256/how-to-find-a-quadratic-form-that-represents-a-prime/1416269))

Is it enough to just find quadratic residues of $p$ (as candidates for the discriminant) and count which ones are 0 or 1 modulo 4, or is it more involved (as in "class number" complicated)? And can the resulting number of forms be deduced from $p$ using more elementary means? Is it always finite? Does it have any asymptotic behavior?

Comment: For any discriminant $d$ whose residue mod $p$ is a square, there is at least one form of discriminant $d$ representing $p$, so this number will always be infinite. You could instead ask how many forms of a given discriminant represent $p$, to which I think the answer is $|C/C^2|$ where $C$ is the class group of forms with discriminant $d$.

Comment: For a fixed discriminant, there are either one or two "reduced" forms that represent a prime; if two, they are "opposite" classes. The same is true of indefinite forms, but now the equivalence classes take more work, and "reduced" is less familiar.  There is still a "reduction" for indefinite forms. My favorite treatment is Binary Quadratic Forms by Duncan Buell.

Comment: Why not: the original definition of $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2$ being indefinite and reduced is equivalent to this: $ac < 0$  and $b > |a+c| \; . \; \;$ her $a,b,c$ are ordinary integers. This is stated and proved in a book by Franz Lemmermeyer

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I guess what I meant to ask (and did not put it very well) was how many of the quadratic residues of p have a fighting chance of being a discriminant of one of the representing form (providing that I understand correctly the condition that discriminant d has to be 0 or 1 mod 4).

Comment: @TamrefRelue in that formulation the answer will always be $\frac{p-1}{2}$ since for every quadratic residue $a$ mod $p$ you can always find a representative for $a$ which is equal to $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, by CRT.

Comment: Thanks Ethan - that puts my mind at pease.